# jQuery array selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been using jQuery for YEARS, yet only now I've seen something like this:

`$('#child', '#parent')`

Apparently it matches the `#child` element. But I can't find any mention of that technique in the official documentation. Can someone possibly explain this behaviour and provide more examples?

Cheers!

Comment: That's the context parameter, just as statetd in DOC even this isn't valid as string selector. It works but isn't supported

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context

Comment: FYI, i find this link: https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/295 regarding string not being valid context even it works (in current jQuery versions)

Comment: Don't use comments for answers- create an answer and let it be accepted.

Comment: Side-note: The specific example shown is pointless anyway as IDs must be unique on the page. i.e. `$('#child')` does the same thing faster.